# AWS Appsync subscription is not triggered when device came to onlne from offline (event triggered when device was offline)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, appsync-apollo-client

1. Subscription Listener is registered in android
2. Make device offline
3. Trigger a mutation from AWS console
4. Make device online

I am expecting the subscription block to be called since there is a mutation(I am getting the subscription when device is online)

Is there any way to get the subscription which was triggered when the device was offline ?

Answer (score 0):

Subscription listeners are only for realtime notifications while the device is online. AppSync will bring your local data up to date with whatever changes were made while offline but the subscription listener won't fire for all events which happened while offline.